# Triggering callback after rendering login form from rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

I am building a single-page-app with rails and client-side javascript.  To dynamically manage the interface, I need to trigger a callback after the login form view (loginForm.html.erb) is returned (for user authentication via Bcrypt).  I've tried jquery $.ajax requests, and can get the form OR the json responses but not both.

Here's the request to get the login form:

```
loginMenuEl.on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/login",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(jsonData) {
        self.initLoginButton();
        self.processContent(jsonData);
    }).fail(function(){
        console.log("*** ajax fail L1 ***");
    });
});
```

Here are the relavent routes:

```
get "/login" => "sessions#login"
get "/loginForm" => "sessions#loginForm"
get "/login_attempt" => "sessions#login_attempt"
post "/login_attempt" => "sessions#login_attempt"
```

Here is the Sessions controller that processes the form and json:

```
def login
    @contentInfo = Content.find_by_id(1)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :loginForm }
        format.json { render json: @contentInfo }
    end
end
```

I've tried other versions of the respond_to block but the form never returns:

```
format.html { redirect_to (:action => 'loginForm') }
format.html { redirect_to (action: 'loginForm') }
format.html { redirect_to action: 'loginForm' }
format.json { render json: @contentInfo }
```

Am I correct to believe that rails can return both json and a view file (loginForm.html.erb)

Comment: Rails can't return BOTH the html and the json, just one at the time.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid of that.  Is there another way to trigger a callback that doesn't involve ajax?  ...something triggered by fully loading the form into <%= yield %>?

Comment: have you tried getting the json data in a success callback of the ajax request for the form?